# Приоритет условий в запросе

Tags: sql

Возможно ли в одном условие вместить следующие условие.

```
select count(*) from `order_delivery_address` where `order_delivery_address_city`  != 'Липецк' and `order_price` <= 333
```

Чтобы при цене менее 333, даже при условии, что город=Липецк, строка попадала в выборку? Т.е. если выполняется второе условие, первое игнорируется.

Comment: А почему бы тогда вообще не убрать условие проверяющее город на НЕ Липецк ?

Comment: Потому что в этой выборке я хочу получить список заказов, не содержащих определенных городов, но если в этих заказах цена не удовлетворяет условию, пусть даже город из списка,который я не хочу видеть, то все равно вывести заказ.

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите получить любые цены по городам которые не в списке, но если цена меньше 333 то по всем городам ? Но тогда вам надо использовать OR вместо AND

Comment: @Mike что-то под вечер совсем плохо у меня с логикой, тут в самом деле простой or подходит(видимо отрицание в условии сбило). спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Чтобы при цене менее 333, даже при условии, что город=Липецк, строка попадала в выборку?

```
where NOT (order_delivery_address_city = 'Липецк' and order_price > 333)
```

?